# How to get all the span value with Selenium WebDriver using Java?

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to get all the span value with class of wd4 for by following code:

```
List <WebElement> we = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='lottery']/li/span"));
```

HTML :

```
<li data-id="20151105031XJ500wh0001" data-istrace="0" class="evenTr first">
    <span class="wd1">2015-11-05 16:10:58</span>
    <span class="wd5">3D福彩</span>
    <span title="一码不定胆">一码不定胆</span>
    <span class="wd2">2015302</span>
    <span class="wd3">元</span>
    <span class="grid-toggle" alt="号码详情：">
        <div class="wrapbox">
            <em alt="2">2</em>
        </div>
    </span>
    <span class="wd4">1</span>
    <span>¥2</span>
    <span>¥0</span>
    <span class="wd4">未开奖</span>
    <span alt="开奖号码："></span>
    <span class="wd3">否</span>
</li>
```

Indeed the code i trying to implement , its getting null value. Kindly advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<String> spanText= new ArrayList<String>();
List <WebElement> we = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='evenTr']/span[@class='wd4']"));
for(WebElement w : we) {
    spanText.add(w.getText());
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help

Comment: @wincengn - Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

// Page elements :

```
 <StartTag: span> xyz</EndTag: span>
```

You can try this:
re-frame the xpath as :

```
 //span[contains(.,'xyz')]//
```

final code will be :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'xyz')]").getText();
```

Comment: i don't think your answer will suit for me as i need get a list of the value in the class of wd4 which wd4 have different kind of value.